# What's the purpose of immediately rethrowing all Exceptions?

Tags: php, exception, doctrine-orm, doctrine

The [documentation for Doctrine ORM](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) says:

> Note that when catching `Exception` you should generally re-throw the exception.

Why would you do that? What's the rationale for it? Why not *not* use a `try/catch` block? Wouldn't this:

```php
try {
  /** @var EntityManager $em */
  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();
} catch (EntityException $e){
  throw  $e;
} catch (\Exception $e){
  throw  $e;
}
```

be the same as this?

```php
/** @var EntityManager $em */
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

What's the purpose of immediately rethrowing all Exceptions?

Comment: CJ Dennis, any feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are functionally equivalent, but that's not what the quoted phrase refers to.

The quote you mention comes from the chapter on Transactions and Concurrency, specifically to [explicitly demarcated transactions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#exception-handling).

The quote refers to this kind of code:

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    //... do some work
    $user = new User;
    $user->setName('George');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

In this case, the transaction is demarcated first by the `beginTransaction()` and the `commit()` calls.

If you do not use a `catch` block for this, there is no way for you to issue a `rollBack()`, and you would leave the transaction open. Yes, it `may` rollback automatically when the connection closes, but it's better if you do it explicitly.

And the re-throwing the exception is advisable so you can let consumers know that something went wrong with the transaction, and do proper error handling. You could also throw a different kind of exception, or do a different kind of error handling.

Comment: I thought that was what they meant. It looks like the previous developers took the advice literally!